# How do you retrieve one of the pallet brushes from the Material Design in XAML toolkit using C# Code Behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

My pathetic attempt to retrieve one:

```
MaterialDesign.Themes.Wpf.Current.Brushes.MaterialDesignBody
```

(which doesn't work, of course.)

The documentation for the brushes is [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Brush-Names).  The brushes themselves appear to be located [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml); I can get to them in xaml, but don't know how to get to them in C#.

If anyone knows which brush controls text color, I would be grateful for that as well.  Bonus points for retrieving a brush from the currently-selected theme.

Comment: `Application.Current.TryFindResource("PrimaryHueLightBrush");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are resources.

In a `FrameworkElement`, you could retrive one using the `FindResource` method:

```
SolidColorBrush MaterialDesignBody = FindResource("MaterialDesignBody") as SolidColorBrush;
```

You could also use the `TryFindResource` method of the `Application` class:

```
SolidColorBrush MaterialDesignBody = Application.Current.TryFindResource("MaterialDesignBody") as SolidColorBrush;
```

This will give you the brush for the currently selected theme, provided that you have merged it into your `App.xaml` file, e.g.:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the resources are inserted into the application resource dictionary, the following would do:

```
Application.Current.TryFindResource("PrimaryHueLightBrush")
```